# How to change mat-input text colour after move to next form control?

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I am using mat-Input field , after the entered text inside mat-input
i am move to next form control, when i move to next form control i want to change my mat-input text colour.[mat-form-field(mat-input)](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in style.css file.

```css
.mat-focused input.mat-input-element{
  color: rgb(188, 151, 86);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(188,151,86) !important;
}
```